# Can I do Google +1 for my own sites?

Tags: seo, google, social-media

Is it safe to +1 my own sites with google's new +1 button. I've added this button to my web pages but would there be any detrimental effect of clicking this link myself and +1 my own pages?

Comment: Is there any way that Google can link you to the web pages - do you use webmaster tools or analytics for example? Does your google profile list one of your sites in it?

Comment: +1 only works if you are logged into a google account. This account is the same as I use for webmasters, analytics so google knows that they are my sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Go for it.** If you like your own content, there seems little reason (beyond retaining some sense of modesty) not to recommend it to your friends.

There's no logical reason for Google to penalise you for plus-one-ing<sup>1</sup> your own sites, just as there's no logical reason for Facebook to penalise you for liking your own Facebook page. Google +1 is currently used only to provide recommendations within search results for people Google thinks you may know, not to increase your position.

From ["how does +1 affect search results"](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1140194):

> +1 helps people discover relevant content from the people they
>   already know and trust. Adding the +1
>   button to your pages lets users
>   recommend your content, knowing that
>   their friends and contacts will see
>   their recommendation in the context of Google
>   search results.

As such, the only thing clicking +1 on your sites will do is to put your name next to your site if a person Google thinks is connected to you (e.g. a user logged into Gmail who you've contacted before) does a search that results in your site appearing in the results.

It's possible that Google may use +1 as part of their ranking algorithm in future but, even if they did, a single recommendation from one user -- regardless of who it is -- is unlikely to make much difference anyway.

---

<sup>1: There must be a better verb for this, but I can't think of one.</sup>

Comment: Simply "plussing" rolls off the tongue a little easier :)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Thank you. That's much better. I'll let my original stand, but 'plussing' is what I'll use on those rare times it crops up from now on.

Comment: Since other social tools use "like" and "friend" and "follow" without the ...ing we could just use "plus".

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - you can't +1 yourself. The box simple turns red and has a ! in it. Looks like they just don't allow people to +1 sites that belong to themselves. I found out by clicking on my links. Either you can't +1 yourself or my +1 box doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried logging out of all Google services before tapping the +1 button? That might help you discern whether the button's broken or not.

Comment: You must be logged in to a google account of +1 doesn't work. It's a social network tool so it needs to know who your contacts and friends are. I could log into another google account but that has would have no contacts or friends attached to it so the +1 would be ineffective.

Comment: Perhaps ask someone else who is logged into a Google service to try clicking your +1 buttons? I can't see how Google would 'know' that you own the service (even Webmaster Tools/Analytics etc. don't prove a site is yours), so it's possible the button's simply broken.